# Is it possible to get statistics with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, statistics

Is it possible to get statistics about each users contributions, total line count etc?

Comment: Not specific enough. What type of stats? I would need specific metrics of the repository, performance, size, etc. -- so far, no known client (front or backend) delivers this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can get basic statistics by using "Show Log..." and then "Statistics" (Button at the bottom IIRC)

Comment: Make sure to click "Show all" before "Statistics" to get the complete history from the SVN server. Otherwise the statistics are incomplete as they cover only the show commits.

Comment: That works, however is within the tool itself. Nothing can be extracted or used. The presentation is - to speak friendly - 1990s styled.

Answer (score 16):

TortoiseSVN is not capable of gathering statistics (That I'm aware of).

I have used [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). It can put together graphs and provide all sorts of statistics; including user contributions (Percentage of total changes, lines of code, lines per change) and so-on.

Comment: I want to -1 for saying Tortoise has no statistics support, but +1 for suggesting a program with better support. So, On balance you just get this comment

Comment: Note. StatSVN last release is 0.7.0 and 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as detailed [in the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/bigpicture.html) if you're not too fussy about how much you can drill down into the results

Answer (score 0):

If you want stats on a specific date range and repository, right-click on the repo folder your interested in and select "TortoiseSVN" -> "Show log".

From the show log window there should be a "Statistics" button.

To alter the date range on the stats, adjust the "From:" and "To:" dates and then click the "Statistics" button again.