# How to compare two files in Python and list how many lines are changed

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-diffs

I need to compare the two files in Python and then count the number of lines that are changed.

Problem Statement:
I have to give a report on monthly basis, that in a project, how many files are present and how many lines each file has and during the time frame of one month, how many lines are changed.
So I want to automate this process.
So, firstly I started with writing a Python Script which will generate a Excel file containing the number of lines in each file in all the sub-directories of the project directory. This part is done.

Now provided that, I have the Source Code copy from 31st Oct and 30th Nov in two separate directories and, I want to check how many lines are changed during this time interval.
Can you guys help me with this, I really don't understand how to proceed further.

Comment: why not use source control?  It would give you a lot of information?  If you need to as well, you might be able to use some bash scripts to diff A and B, but what about the interum of say, A and B and C....   like what if you end up changing a line twice, do you count it twice, or just once?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: We are using SVN and as a GUI client tortoiseSVN, does it generate this information automatically?
For changing line twice question, that's why I want to take revision at the starting of month and then at the end of month, by this we will check the final changes and not the in between changes.

Comment: Depends on how you want to do it.  If you want to use your visual Tool, you should follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412129/is-it-possible-to-get-statistics-with-tortoisesvn If you want to get a bit more custom, you should look into the CLI for `svn diff` and maybe run a `grep` and `wc` or few.